# Can MyPy infer the signatures of dynamically generated functions?

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

Suppose I have a function that takes in a function and produces a new function that calls the original function twice with two different sets of inputs:

```py
def duplicate(f):
  def g(args1, args2):
    return (f(*args1), f(*args2))
  return g
```

Is there a way to provide type annotations for this function so that mypy will be able to infer the signature of `g` based upon `f`? In particular, if I supplied:

```py
def f(a: int, b: str):
  ...
```

and produced:

```py
g = duplicate(f)
```

I'd like it to be able to be inferred that the signature of `g` is `(int, str, int, str) -> ...` but I'm not aware of how to accomplish this.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think thats within reach of static type checking.